# I want to split a text by dot and space, the code is posted its giving me an error "str object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

the code is posted its giving me an error "str object cannot be interpreted as an integer" is there anyone who can fix ?

```
file =  open(r'C:\Users\Raja Arsalan\Desktop\read_file.txt')


for i in file:
     words= i.rstrip()
     print("FRIST WORD" ,words)

     letter = words.split("."," ")
     print(letter)
```

Comment: The code you posted, on its own, does not reproduce that problem. Please include the **full traceback** of the error, and add any other code you may have that makes the code (run separately) actually raise that exception.

Comment: There are multiple possibilities to what other code has done to lead to this situation, but only a traceback can tell me which one is the more likely scenario. You *probably* bound `open` or `print` to something else, something that expects an integer when called. That can be as simple as `print = int` (which would raise `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` for the `print("FRIST WORD" ,words)` line).

Comment: when i split by just one character like split just by space or just by a dot then it works fine but when ever i try spliting by both of them it throws me an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import re
file =  open(r'C:\Users\Raja Arsalan\Desktop\read_file.txt')

for i in file:
     words= i.rstrip()
     print("FRIST WORD" ,words)

```
 #letter = words.split(".")#," ")
 letter = re.split('. |  ',words)
 print(letter)
```